# Using javascript and html to obtain values and do math, but if one value is empty then answer returns empt

Tags: javascript, html, math

So I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function Calc() {
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').value;

    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').value;

    var Value3 = document.getElementById('Value3').value;

    var answer = Value1 * Value2 * Value3;

    document.getElementById('Answer').value = answer;
}
</script>

<button id="roll" onclick="Calc()">Button</button>
<p>ValueCalcGiveTitle
    <p>Enter first value:
        <input type="text" id='Value1' size="3" />
        <br/>Second value:
        <input type="text" id='Value2' size="3" />
        <br/>Third value:
        <input type="text" id='Value3' size="3" />
        <br/>Answer:
        <input type="text" id='Answer' size="3" disabled='disabled' />
    </p>
</p>
```

This works fine until one box is left blank. Eventually I would have multiple boxes and the user would just use them as necessary, but the with the current code, if one box is left empty, then the answer is zero. This makes sense since a blank value would mean zero, but how do I stop that from happening?

Comment: There is more wrong here than just an incorrect answer when one box is left blank.  What happens, for example, if you put `One` in the textbox instead of `1`?

Comment: @Claies lol exactly what I was thinking

Comment: Define "works fine". It works exactly as coded: if one field is left blank, the result is 0 since that field returns an empty string, and an empty string converted to a Number (courtesy of the `*` operator) is 0. Anything multiplied by zero is zero. So it "works" perfectly.

Comment: You probably want to parse your input values instead of assuming the user will put in something that coerces to a number.  And also check your parsed values using `isNaN()` before using them to do math.

Comment: @aroth—I think you mean validate that the values convert to valid numbers.

Comment: @RobG - Yes, validate.  In my view, by parsing using `parseInt()`.  This doesn't strike me as a case where you want to rely upon JavaScript's automatic coercion of strings to numbers, particularly give that coercing `""` to `0` is not necessarily intuitive and has already caused the OP some confusion.

Comment: if (x== null || x== "") should work

Comment: @DianaPapukchieva—`x==null` will never be true, since the value of a form control is a string, and no string is `==` to *null*.

Comment: @aksharagarwal - Here's my suggestion:  http://jsfiddle.net/1zLqnzmo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several answers here already, however I'm not sure if any of them are really what you're looking for.  At the very least they tend to have the problem in that if the user types an explicit `0` in any box it will be ignored, potentially causing nonsensical results.  For instance, a couple of the answers here will produce a result of `1` for `0 * 0 * 0`.

My assumption is that you want to ignore empty fields, but honor the value(s) that the user provides if they enter a literal value of `0` in one or more inputs.  To accomplish that, I'd suggest the following:

```
function multiply() {
    var result = NaN;
    for (var index = 0; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var value = parseInt(arguments[index], 10);
        if (! isNaN(value)) {
            result = isNaN(result) ? value : result * value;
        }
    }

    return isNaN(result) ? "" : result;
}
```

...and, since you've also asked about how to compute the average:

```
function average() {
    var result = NaN;
    var validNumbers = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var value = parseInt(arguments[index], 10);
        if (! isNaN(value)) {
            result = isNaN(result) ? value : result + value;
            validNumbers++;
        }
    }

    return isNaN(result) ? "" : (result * 1.0 / validNumbers).toFixed(2);
}
```

The main difference here is that I'm using [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to convert the input value to a number, as opposed to relying upon JavaScript's [implicit coercion](http://webreflection.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html) of string values to numbers (which as you've noticed will treat `""` as `0`).  This means that if the user leaves a box empty, you'll get [NaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number_nan.asp) instead of `0`.  You can then use [isNaN()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) to check for (and ignore) anything that was not entered as a valid number.

There's a working example below (and also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1zLqnzmo/1/)):

```js
window.Calc = function() {
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').value;
    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').value;
    var Value3 = document.getElementById('Value3').value;

    var product = multiply(Value1, Value2, Value3);
    document.getElementById('Answer').value = product;
    
    var avg = average(Value1, Value2, Value3);
    document.getElementById('average').value = avg;
}

window.multiply = function() {
    var result = NaN;
    for (var index = 0; index < arguments.length; index++) {
     var value = parseInt(arguments[index], 10);
        if (! isNaN(value)) {
         result = isNaN(result) ? value : result * value;
        }
    }
    
    return isNaN(result) ? "" : result;
};

window.average = function() {
 var result = NaN;
    var validNumbers = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < arguments.length; index++) {
     var value = parseInt(arguments[index], 10);
        if (! isNaN(value)) {
         result = isNaN(result) ? value : result + value;
            validNumbers++;
        }
    }
    
    return isNaN(result) ? "" : (result * 1.0 / validNumbers).toFixed(2);
};
```

```html
<button id="roll" onclick="Calc()">Button</button>
<p>ValueCalcGiveTitle
    <p>Enter first value:
        <input type="text" id='Value1' size="3" />
        <br/>Second value:
        <input type="text" id='Value2' size="3" />
        <br/>Third value:
        <input type="text" id='Value3' size="3" />
        <br/>Product:
        <input type="text" id='Answer' size="3" disabled='disabled' />
        <br/>Average:
        <input type="text" id='average' size="3" disabled='disabled' />
    </p>
</p>
```

Comment: This worked very well, thank you. I just had one more concern. Currently I am having a user select how many values he/she has and displaying a different function with forms under a collapsible part. Instead of doing this (much more work) is there an easier way to make a function to add more fields/values? I can just put 20 and have them ignored as yours does, but it would be better if I could have a button where you add fields.

Answer (score 4):

You could just make a simple function

```
function multNonZeros(numbers) {
    var total = 1;
    for (var j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        if (!isNaN(eval(numbers[j])))
            total *= eval(numbers[j]);
    }
    return total;
}
```

then the JS would be

```
function Calc() {
    var values = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        values[i] = document.getElementById('Value' + (i + 1)).value;
    }

    var answer = multNonZeros(values);
    console.log(values);

    document.getElementById('Answer').value = answer;
}
```

This still includes any numbers that are valid, but ignores blank or invalid ones.

EDIT: Updated it to allow the number 0 but only if it was an actual input from the user

Comment: Also, is this an incorrect variable to make? var average = (Value1 + Value2 + Value3)/3;    It returns very odd values for some reason

Comment: That average code looks like it should work. Probably something else in you're code that's causing it. Try console.logging the values and see that they are correct in the first place.

Comment: Won't this code fail if the user provides an explicit value of `0` for one of their three inputs?

Comment: Yes; I originally read the question in a hurry, and thought that that was one of the things he wanted - Just re-read it and changed my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many input values with the function below:

```
function Calc(){
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id*=Value]');//Select all inputs that have "Value" in the id
  var answer=0;
  [].forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {//Iterate over the input list
      if(!answer){//Set answer to the first input value 
          answer = input.value;
      }else{
        if(input.value){//Only multiply if value is truthy 
            answer = input.value * answer;
        }
     }
  }); 
  document.getElementById('Answer').value = answer;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/yd03yzqs/

Answer (score 0):

As Claies notes, there's lots to be fixed here, but to get what you're trying to achieve you can just do:

```
function Calc() {
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').value || 1;

    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').value || 1;

    var Value3 = document.getElementById('Value3').value || 1;

    var answer = Value1 * Value2 * Value3;

    document.getElementById('Answer').value = answer;
}
```

`""` is a falsey value so the variables will default to 1 if nothing is entered.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This solution fixes the problem where an input is left blank. As I note in the post, issues where non-numbers are entered will also need fixed, but I didn't purport to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very simple in an if statement to check and see if there are values present within all 3 inputs. Obviously, as Claies mentioned, there is more to worry about here but based on your question, the below code will work:

```
function Calc() {
    var Value1 = document.getElementById('Value1').value;

    var Value2 = document.getElementById('Value2').value;

    var Value3 = document.getElementById('Value3').value;

    if (Value1.length > 0 && Value2.length > 0 && Value3.length > 0) {
        var answer = Value1 * Value2 * Value3;
        document.getElementById('Answer').value = answer;
    }
    else {
        alert("All inputs need to have a number before calculating!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Calc(){
var a = document.getElementById('Value1');
    var b = document.getElementById('Value2');
    var c = document.getElementById('Value3');
    var kinput = new array(a,b,c);
    var sum = 1;
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(!isNaN(kinput[i])){
            sum*=kinput[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```